# Как средствами AndroidStudio узнать какой алгоритм лучше?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

У меня есть несколько алгоритмов. Как узнать средствами AndroidStudio какой из этих алгоритмов работает быстрее? Насколько сильно они грузят CPU или GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.System.nanoTime()` в помощь - насчёт Performance Counter. Насчёт GPU, когда вы последний раз видели LagCouter от GPU ведра? Я его последний раз видел в версиях 1-4 в 2010х годах... Сейчас у меня на телефоне 11я ведра, вроде как 12я последняя и там вообще жалоб на GPU нету, чипы тупо превзошли рынок потребностей. Я про GPU вообще не парюсь, тупо - сри в процессор он пережуёт.